# WordPress site building w/ slider absolute paths before client domain registered or DNS transfer

Tags: wordpress, path, transfer, absolute

I’m wondering if I’m handling the procedure for pre-building Word Press sites inefficiently.  I’ve followed http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and I’m curious if this is the only way to prevent difficulties with sliders, image links, etc..

The short question is – can you build WP sites remotely without interrupting clients domain / hosting when the end result will be on a different Go Daddy server?  I’ve done this but end up with broken sliders, and lots to basically “redo”.

Here’s what I’m trying to accomplish and some of the difficulties experienced…

1. Build a WP site on Go Daddy server BEFORE client domain and hosting are moved or transferred.  This tends to get troublesome because client wants to view new site before letting go of their LIVE domain site.  When adding a slider(s) – images are absolute paths so I have to either reupload and relink all slider images or only do 1 or 2 images then add the rest AFTER the domain move.
2. Not able to use Go Daddy Preview DNS because I believe this is for when the domain already exists on the server I’m working on (correct?)  Otherwise, okay method except for having to relink and redo the slider images just like in #1 above.
3. Is there a way of registering a domain like www.testsite.com and do all my work there, then when client approves, MOVE their domain and use Go Daddy hosting, flip a switch and done?  The www.testsite.com would be on Go Daddy but different owner account (my own).

Or does everyone go through this and I just need to account for it and bill for extra time involved when relinking slider images?  Main problem is slider images having absolute paths.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using absolute paths. Otherwise when you port your files to the new server, you will have broken images and links.

You should also be exporting the database from your testing server, then changing the path names in the database to point to your production server.

Exporting from within Wordpress is not enough. You must export / import your DB.

Please see this tutorial on how to export your database and configure. http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/exporting-and-importing-wordpress

Also, if you're going to manually add paths to files, or link a button for example, you must use relative paths. (as I said above)

For example: /wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/images/slider_image.jpg

This will be the same regardless of the server your on. So that path will work, even when you move the website to the production server.

Comment: Thank you.  The absolute paths are out of my control in regards to 'sliders'.  I'm not purposely setting absolute paths.  When using image sliders they simply function that way such as "thethe fly" slider plugin.  Thank you for the advice on relative paths for manual paths and links.